# Print file without adding trailing newline with awk

Tags: awk, newline, cmp

I'm using awk to process some program files, removing debugging sections. Some of these files have no trailing newline. I'd like to have awk print the file line by line, with newlines, but without adding an extra newline at the end if it's not present.

E.g.

```
a
b // no newline after the "b"
```

is getting turned into this:

```
a
b<NEWLINE>
```

The reason that I don't want to add this newline is that I'm trying to use `cmp --silent $file $file_without_debug_sections` to determine whether to use the original file or the new one. And the reason that I care about *that* is that I'm trying to limit the number of files that have the debug extension in my compiler output. Only using the non-debug version if it's different also makes it clear which files were changed by this "remove debug sections" process.

So to summarize, how can I get awk to go through the file line by line, but without adding a newline at the end if one doesn't already exist?

My current code looks like this:

```
{    
    if ($0 ~ /^[ \t]*\/\/[ \t]*\/\*[ \t]*begin[ \t]+debug[ \t]*$/) { 
        print "/* begin debug"; 
    } else if ($0 ~ /^[ \t]*\/\/[ \t]*end[\ t]+debug[\t ]*\*\/[ \t]*$/) { 
        print "end debug */";
    } else print;
}
```

I tried replacing the `print` at the end there with `printf "%s", $0`. But then it instead omits a newline from every line.

Comment: Why? Source code files without a newline at the end are considered bad practice..

Comment: @hek2mgl I'd personally prefer to see one at the end too but Windows tools don't really care.

Comment: @TomFenech At least git would complain about that, also on Windows. Btw, on Linux it is pretty a hack to even produce a file without a newline at the end. :)

Comment: @hek2mgl I agree that source code files should have a newline at the end, but in the event that it's forgotten and/or we haven't converted them, I'd like the script to still work. BBEdit (on OS X) doesn't by default insert a newline at the end, so I wouldn't say it requires a "hack". However, it does have a "Ensure file ends with line break" setting, which should probably have been checked.

Comment: If *GNU* awk use `RT` to output the same terminator *or lack of any* as found on input. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html

Comment: I'm not sure if I can completely follow you but in any case use `print` instead `printf "%s", $0`.. Otherwise you remove *any* linebreaks..

Comment: @hek2mgl The existing script does use `print`. (Sorry if that wasn't clear.) What's above was my "show your work" at trying to get the newline issue resolved. Using `print` is what causes the issue of the newline being appended when it's not there in the original. [[EDITED the post to make it less confusing]]

Comment: I would simply keep it as `print`, but remove the trailing the newline (temporarily, if it's there) before doing the `cmp` command. Simply compare the files without taking a possible newline at the end into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the fact that `awk` appends a newline at the end if it is missing, like this:

```
# Let's say file1 does not contain a newline at the end. Since
# awk will add a newline at the end if it is missing, file1_debug
# WILL contain a newline at the end.
awk -f remove_debug.awk file1 > file1_debug

# Use awk again before comparing the files, this makes sure that when
# we compare them, both files have a newline at the end.
if cmp --silent <(awk '1' file1) <(awk '1' file1_debug) ; then
    echo "The files are the same"
else
    echo "The files differ"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice solution to the problem. I tried to figure out a way around it with awk, but it appears it's really impossible to tell from within (standard) awk whether it ends in a newline or not.

Answer (score 4):

Change your `print line` statements to `printf "%s%s", line, RT`

For example

```
$ seq 3 > s3
$ head -c -1 s3 > s3nn                      # remove last newline
$ awk '$1=$1{printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' s3nn
1
2
3$ awk '$1=$1' s3nn
1
2
3
$ cat s3nn
1
2
3$
```

in your case `print` without arguments is equal to `print $0`

Comment: `RT` is a feature limited to `gawk`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615809/print-file-without-adding-trailing-newline-with-awk#comment56978477_34615809

Comment: Nice to know there is a way. Too bad I'm not using the GNU version.